# Cannot find symbol class ActivityEngageBindingImpl

Tags: android, mvvm, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm using rxjava2 + mvvvmhabit library. How to fix this issue?

```
Cannot find symbol class ActivityEngageBindingImpl
[databinding] {"msg":"Cannot resolve type \u0027LayoutManagers\u0027",
"file":"app/src/main/res/layout/activity_engage.xml",
"pos":[{"line0":34,"col0":37,"line1":34,"col1":50}]}
```

My activity_engage.xml file

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
    xmlns:binding="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <import type="me.tatarka.bindingcollectionadapter2.LayoutManagers" />
        <import type="me.goldze.mvvmhabit.binding.viewadapter.recyclerview.LineManagers" />
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.founicy.analy.ui.activity.engage.EngageViewModel" />

    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/tb_engage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorBackground"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
            app:titleTextAppearance="@style/CustomToolbar" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_engage_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tb_engage"
            binding:itemBinding="@{viewModel.itemBinding}"
            binding:items="@{viewModel.observableList}"
            binding:layoutManager="@{LayoutManagers.linear()}"
            binding:lineManager="@{LineManagers.horizontal()}"
            android:scrollbarSize="3dp"
            android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scroll_bar_color"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_empty_engage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="@{viewModel.llEmptyEngageVisible}">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="56dp"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_data_empty" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/date_empty"
                android:textColor="@color/textGrey"
                android:textSize="@dimen/engage_card_text" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pb_engage"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the previous version of library. You should remove 4.0.0 and use 2.2.0

```
implementation 'me.tatarka.bindingcollectionadapter2:bindingcollectionadapter:4.0.0'
implementation 'me.tatarka.bindingcollectionadapter2:bindingcollectionadapter-recyclerview:4.0.0'
implementation 'me.tatarka.bindingcollectionadapter2:bindingcollectionadapter-viewpager2:4.0.0'
```

Use 2.2.0 version

```
implementation 'me.tatarka.bindingcollectionadapter2:bindingcollectionadapter:2.2.0'
implementation 'me.tatarka.bindingcollectionadapter2:bindingcollectionadapter-recyclerview:2.2.0'
```